# Same stored procedure acts differently on two/(three) different IDEs

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, pentaho, toad

I just created a stored procedure in MS SQL DB using TOAD.

what it does is that it accepts an ID wherein some records are associated with, then it inserts those records to a table.

next part of the stored procedure is to use the ID input to search on the table where the items got inserted and then return it as the result set to the user just to confirm that the information got inserted.

IN TOAD, it does what is expected. It inserts date and returns information using just the stored procedure.

IN Oracle SQL developer however, it does the insert and it ends at that. It seems to not execute the 2nd part of the stored procedure which is a select stmt.

I just have a feeling that this is because of the jdbc adapter. Also why I'm asking is because I'm using a reporting tool Pentaho Report Designer and it would really make it easier if I can do 2 things at the same time. Pentaho Report Designer is also using jdbc adapters, not a coincidence maybe?

But if there are other things that I can tweak I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems unlikely that it doesn't execute part of it; perhaps more likely that SQL Developer just isn't displaying the result set automatically? Depends how you're calling it perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but worth considering...

There are things called "Batches", where are sets of SQL Statements that are all sent to the server at once, and executed by the server as one set of statements, within a single server-side session.  Sending a set of sql statements to the server as a batch will often result in different results than if you sent them one at a time, where each statement is executed in its own session.

I haven't used Toad (or Oracle) in a while, but as I recall, it dealt with batches differently than the other ide I used. If the second statement in your set is relying on being in the same session as the first, and in one ide it is in a separate session, then this might explain what is happening.